# I want to filter LoadData data by an ID (IdFase)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a Datatable Ajax, but I want to filter the data by an ID, currently I am trying a .Where(a => a.IdFase == id) but it is not working, my LoadData is being loaded in my controller Index.

```
    public IActionResult LoadData(int id)
    {
        // Filtra las acciones por el id proporcionado
        var acciones = _context.Acciones
            .Where(a => a.IdFase == id)
            .Include(a => a.IdAspectoNavigation)
            .Include(a => a.IdFaseNavigation)
            .Include(a => a.IdUsuarioNavigation)
            
            .ToList();

        var jsonData = acciones.Select(accione => new
        {
            idAccion = accione.IdAccion,
            nombreAccion = accione.NombreAccion,
            idAspectoNavigation = accione.IdAspectoNavigation?.NombreAspecto,
            idFaseNavigation = accione.IdFaseNavigation?.NombreFase,
            idUsuarioNavigation = accione.IdUsuarioNavigation?.IdUsuario,
            fechaInicio = accione.FechaInicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            fechaVencimiento = accione.FechaVencimiento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        });

        return Json(new { data = jsonData });
    }

}



<script type="text/javascript">
    var js = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    
    js(document).ready(function () {
        js('#accionesTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Acciones/LoadData', // Agrega el id a la URL
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        var editButton = '<a href="/Acciones/Edit/' + row.idAccion + '" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>';
                        var detailsButton = '<a href="/Acciones/Details/' + row.idAccion + '" class="btn btn-info">Detalles</a>';
                        var deleteButton = '<a href="/Acciones/Delete/' + row.idAccion + '" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>';
                        return editButton + " | " + detailsButton + " | " + deleteButton;
                    }
                },
                { "data": "nombreAccion" },
                { "data": "idAspectoNavigation" },
                { "data": "idFaseNavigation" },
                { "data": "idUsuarioNavigation" },
                { "data": "fechaInicio" },
                { "data": "fechaVencimiento" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the data to be filtered. For example, to show the data that is only from the IdFase depending on the id of the url.

Comment: You didn't provide the value for `id` in "/Acciones/LoadData". Thus by default `id` will be 0.